Object Mapper readValue function returns Null in Spring Boot 3
Below is my response POJO Class
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductResponse {
    boolean required;
    ProductModel model;
}

Below is my code where I'm trying to read values using object mapper.
ProductResponse response;

        try {
            response =  objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), ProductResponse.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          
        }

Below is an example of object mapper configuration:
@Configuration
public class CommonBeans {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}

Can someone please guide me on what I'm missing? Why the value of the response is null?

Why are you creating your own mapper, spring boot automatically creates one. Why are you doing this yourself? This is a reponse so you can just let the RestTemplate or whatever you are using do the mapping for you. also response.getBody() won't work here, this code won't compile.

What response.getBody() outputs is the key to solve this problem.
